# How is this style of cartoon animation produced?

Tags: effects, animation

Back in the early 1990s, *America's Funniest Home Videos* briefly featured an animated sidekick called Stretchy McGillicuddy:

As you can see from the clip, the human host, Bob Saget, would interact with Stretchy by talking to him on a TV screen.

The interaction and animation both look like they're done live and in real time, rather than having Saget talk to a pre-recorded video.  The animation is also a lot smoother and more elastic-looking than traditional cel animation (or at least what we'd expect a low-budget show like *AFV* to produce), and of course, given the time period, it's unlikely that computer graphics were involved.

How was this style of animation produced, and is there a name for the technique?

Comment: The movement seems to suggest this is puppetry, and possibly having the recording altered to look more cartoony by significantly upping the contrast and saturation.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks to @Saki's answer and comments thereon I was able to find [the original US patent for this technique](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3899848), which explains everything. I don't have time at the moment to summarize it in detail but if Saki or someone else wants to do so, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTwJ1fv6t9U